# calculating json data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm learning through angularjs (not 2) and am trying to figure out how to calculate a customer order total.

my data looks like this:

```
var customers = [
            {
                id: 1, 
                joined: '2000-12-02', 
                name:'John', 
                city:'Chandler', 
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        product: 'Shoes',
                        total: 9.9956
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                id: 2, 
                joined: '1965-01-25',
                name:'Zed', 
                city:'Las Vegas', 
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        product: 'Baseball',
                        total: 9.995
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        product: 'Bat',
                        total: 9.995
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

I have a factory and a controller that receives that data and...

my controller looks like:

```
(function() {

    var CustomersController = function ($scope, $log, customerFactory) {
        $scope.sortBy = 'name';
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.customers = [];

        function init () {

            customerFactory.getCustomers()
                .success(function(customers) {
                    $scope.customers = customers;

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status );

            });

        }

        init();

        $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
           $scope.sortBy = propName;
           $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };


    };

    CustomersController.$inject = ['$scope','$log' ,'customerFactory'];

    angular.module('customersApp')
      .controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);

}());
```

my view looks like this:

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
<br /><br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort(name)">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort(city)">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort(joined)">Joined</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
        <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td><a href="#/orders/{{ cust.employeeid }}">View Orders</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<span>Total customers: {{ customers.length }} </span>
```

I understand how I would add in an order total column...but how do you calculate it given the json that comes back?

---------------EDIT--------------

I think this is headed in the right path?

```
    customerFactory.getCustomers()
        .success(function(customers) {
            for(var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                var currCustomer = customers[i];
                var aCustomerTotal = 0;

                if (currCustomer.hrs) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < currCustomer.hrs.length; j++) {
                        aCustomerTotal += parseInt(currCustomer.hrs[j].bllhrs);
                    }
                } else {
                    aCustomerTotal=0
                }
                customers[i].orderTotal = aCustomerTotal;
                console.log(currCustomer.lastname + " total: " + aCustomerTotal);
            }
            // after the exeuction of this logic set your $scope's customer to the modified object.
            $scope.customers = customers;
        })
```

Comment: you have to iterate data and calculate in controller

Comment: also you have to pass property name `ng-click="doSort('name')"` follow the same for other `ng-click`'s

Comment: @charlietfl I think I get that...would that create a new element in `customers` too then? Would I have an `customers.orderTotal` to then?

Comment: that would probably be best. Then it only needs to be calculated once when you get the data. Unless you are editing these and need live calcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are stuck on is getting a total per customer -> you can use a simple double for loop:

```
.success(function(customers) {
    for(var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        var currCustomer = customers[i];
        var aCustomerTotal = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < currCustomer.orders.length; j++) {
            aCustomerTotal += currCustomer.orders[j].total;
        }
        customers[i].orderTotal = aCustomerTotal;
        console.log(currCustomer.name + " total: " + aCustomerTotal);
    }
    // after the exeuction of this logic set your $scope's customer to the modified object.
    $scope.customers = customers;
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this...do I put this in the controller? and if so...how do you append that to `$scope.customers = customers;`?

Comment: I made an edit with what you suggested...but I don't understand how to append the result back to the initial json object...sorry...new to this whole thing...

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to modify the `customer` object with the customer's total and then add that modified object to the scope.

Comment: I edited my answer with what you had but I'm getting an `cannot read property 'length' of undefined` now at the `hrs.length`. Tried to put in an if statement but can't get it to work still...I get 3 results to show in the console but then get the undefined error.

Comment: That means some of your customer objects do not have an `hrs` propety. Check to make sure each one has that property.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) for that (let's say you also use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for simplification):

```
angular.module('customersApp', [])
.filter('customerTotal', function() {
  return function(customer) {
    return _.reduce(customer.hrs, function(sum, hrs) {
      return sum + parseInt(hrs.bllhrs);
    }, 0);
  };
});
```

And you can use that filter like that:

```
<td>{{ curr.name }} total: {{ cust | customerTotal }}</td>
```